# ¿Por que geocoder no me retorna lista de direcciones en android?

Tags: android, google-maps

he buscado varios lugares,pero siempre me retorna un solo resultado y no los 5 como los asigné ,por que será ?

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(Mapszona.this, Locale.getDefault());
int maxResultados = 5;
List<Address> adress = null;
//convertir la ubicacion de texto a latitud y longitud
adress =geo.getFromLocationName(input.getText().toString(),maxResultados);
Log.d(address.size());
```

Comment: Podría ser que para la dirección que metes solo exista un resultado posible (Si es una dirección muy específica, que incluya país, código postal, etc). Qué direcciones has probado? Puedes probar esas mismas direcciones en Google Maps y comparar con lo que te devuelve `getFromLocationName`.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo la misma direccion pongo en google maps y me sale un monton de resultados, lo que busque   fue olivos ,lima y me retorna solo uno o en el peor de los casos me retorna nulo.

Comment: Qué te devuelve `Locale.getDefault()`?

Comment: ya lo he quitado ,y nada, sigue lo mismo